# 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments' instantiating HKWorkoutRouteQuery

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, healthkit, xcode9.4

I'm trying to read the route data of an HKWorkout, but I can't because I get an error in my editor saying 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments' when I try to instantiate an `HKWorkoutRouteQuery` with my retrieved sample.

[image]

As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/reading_route_data), my code looks like this:

```
func getRouteData() -> [(Double)] {
    // Return early if not a distance workout
    guard self.shouldShowDistance else {
        return []
    }

    let store = HKHealthStore()
    let runningObjectQuery = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: self.workout)
    let routeQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: HKSeriesType.workoutRoute(), predicate: runningObjectQuery, anchor: nil, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            // Handle any errors here.
            fatalError("query failed")
        }

        guard samples != nil else {
            fatalError("No samples")
        }

        guard samples!.count > 0 else { fatalError("No samples") }

        guard let route = samples?.first as? HKWorkoutRoute else {
            fatalError("No samples")
        }

        // Create the route query.
        let query = HKWorkoutRouteQuery(route: route) { (query, locationsOrNill, done, errorOrNil) in

            // This block may be called multiple times.

            if let error = errorOrNil {
                // Handle any errors here.
                return
            }

            guard let locations = locationsOrNil else {
                fatalError("*** Invalid State: This can only fail if there was an error. ***")
            }

            // Do something with this batch of location data.

            if done {
                // The query returned all the location data associated with the route.
                // Do something with the complete data set.
            }

            // You can stop the query by calling:
            // store.stop(query)

        }
        store.execute(query)

    }

    store.execute(routeQuery)

    return []
}
```

This makes no sense to me because Apple's own docs require HKWorkoutRouteQuery to be instantiated with a sample.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple got back to me through Bug Reporter. The issue is that I neglected to import CoreLocation. You can fix this error by adding the following line to the top of your file.

```
import CoreLocation
```

As an aside, I think this is a great example of the importance of writing descriptive errors. If the error had mentioned something about the resulting completion requiring `CoreLocation`, I would have been able to solve this on my own.